User variable in kustomize PrometheusRule
I want to reduce copy/paste and have my environments (where I use kustomize) get an alerting rule from the base and then just provide the value.
base/prometheus-alerts.yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  labels:
    release: kube-prometheus-stack
    role: app-rules
    test: $(VAL_A) # This works
  name: xx
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  groups:
    - name: xx
      rules:
        - alert: xx
          annotations:
            description: 'xx'
          expr: sum(rate(xx[5m])) by (container) < $(VAL_A) # This does not

In my testing env I have the following
kustomization.yml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - ../base
vars:
- name: VAL_A
  objref:
    kind: PrometheusRule
    name: connectors-taz-tcp-alerts
    apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
  fieldref:
    fieldpath: data.VAL_A

And then the patch-prometheus-alerts.yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  name: connectors-taz-tcp-alerts
  namespace: monitoring
data:
  VAL_A: "hello-world"

Whenever I run kubectl kustomize . I will get the following:
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
data:
  VAL_A: hello-world
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  labels:
    release: kube-prometheus-stack
    role: app-rules
    test: hello-world
  name: xx
  namespace: xx
spec:
  groups:
  - name: xx
    rules:
    - alert: xx
      annotations:
        [..]
          expr: sum(rate(xx[5m])) by (container) < $(VAL_A)


Why is the label test changed to "hello-world" but not the $(VAL_A) in the expression?

The field vars was deprecated since v5 and the recommended alternative is replacements1.
The updated Kustomize will provide a fix for you out-of-the-box.
I reproduced your setup with the following layout:
.
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yml
│   └── prometheus-alerts.yaml
└── dev
    ├── kustomization.yml
    └── patch-prometheus-alerts.yaml

The contents of base/* are just the same as what you have in your question.
Same goes for dev/patch-prometheus-alerts.yaml.
The only change will be the following:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - ../base
  - patch-prometheus-alerts.yaml
replacements:
  - source:
      fieldPath: data.VAL_A
      group: monitoring.coreos.com
      kind: PrometheusRule
      name: connectors-taz-tcp-alerts
      version: v1
    targets:
      - fieldPaths:
          - metadata.labels.test
        select:
          group: monitoring.coreos.com
          kind: PrometheusRule
          name: xx
          namespace: monitoring
          version: v1
      - fieldPaths:
          - spec.groups.0.rules.0.expr
        options:
          delimiter: " "
          index: 4
        select:
          group: monitoring.coreos.com
          kind: PrometheusRule
          name: xx
          namespace: monitoring
          version: v1

This is the output of running kustomize edit fix --vars in the dev/ directory.
And this is the result when building with kustomize build . (in dev/ directory).
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
data:
  VAL_A: hello-world
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  name: connectors-taz-tcp-alerts
  namespace: monitoring
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  labels:
    release: kube-prometheus-stack
    role: app-rules
    test: hello-world
  name: xx
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  groups:
  - name: xx
    rules:
    - alert: xx
      annotations:
        description: xx
      expr: sum(rate(xx[5m])) by (container) < hello-world


Thank you, that looks like something that could work. I will try it out!

@Matthijs please let me know if you need further help. If the provided answer works for you, please don't forget to mark it as one. Appreciated.
